# How to correctly drag the view around the circle?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, drag

I want the green dot to follow the touch point in a circular path, but it doesn't seem to be doing it right.

[image: Strange behavior GIF illustration]

It seems like there is an unwanted offset somewhere but I can't find it on my own for quite some time.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val touchPoint = remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }

    Scaffold {
        Column() {
            Box(Modifier.height(100.dp).fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Blue))
            Layout(
                modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(1f).fillMaxSize(),
                content = {
                    Box(
                        Modifier
                            .size(48.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .background(Color.Green)
                            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                                detectDragGestures(
                                    onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                                        change.consumeAllChanges()
                                        touchPoint.value += dragAmount
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                    )
                }
            ) { measurables, constraints ->
                val dot = measurables.first().measure(constraints.copy(minHeight = 0, minWidth = 0))

                val width = constraints.maxWidth
                val height = constraints.maxHeight

                val centerX = width / 2
                val centerY = height / 2
                val lengthFromCenter = width / 2 - dot.width / 2

                val touchX = touchPoint.value.x
                val touchY = touchPoint.value.y

                layout(width, height) {
                    // I planned to achieve the desired behaviour with the following steps:

                    // 1. Convert cartesian coordinates to polar ones
                    val r = sqrt(touchX.pow(2) + touchY.pow(2))
                    val angle = atan2(touchY.toDouble(), touchX.toDouble())

                    // 2. Use fixed polar radius
                    val rFixed = lengthFromCenter
                    
                    // 3. Convert it back to cartesian coordinates
                    val x = rFixed * cos(angle)
                    val y = rFixed * sin(angle)
                    
                    // 4. Layout on screen
                    dot.place(
                        x = (x + centerX - dot.width / 2).roundToInt(),
                        y = (y + centerY - dot.height / 2).roundToInt()
                    )
                }
            }
            Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Blue))
        }
    }
}
```

I'm definitely missing something but don't know what exactly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
touchPoint.value += dragAmount
```

Is in `pixel` values, and you're updating the position of the `dot` with `pixel` values, where it requires `dp` values. If you update that with

```
private fun Float.pxToDp(context: Context): Dp = // Float or Int, depends on the value you have, or Double
    (this / context.resources.displayMetrics.density).dp
```

The amount with which it will be moved, will be smaller and reflect the dragging made by the user

Comment: Could you explain why you think so? `place(x, y)` require offset in pixels, not dp.

Comment: I tried it myself, and I'm able to move things around my app with precision using that conversion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using some math:

```
@Composable
fun CircularView(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    var middle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
    }

    var size by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0.dp)
    }

    var dragAngle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(size)) {
        drawCircle(
            color = Color.Red,
            center = middle,
            style = Stroke(1.dp.toPx())
        )
    }
    Layout(
        content = content,
        modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(true) {
            detectDragGestures(
                onDrag = { change, _ ->
                    change.consumeAllChanges()
                    val positionOfDrag = change.position
                    val previousPosition = change.previousPosition

                    dragAngle += atan2(
                        positionOfDrag.x - middle.x,
                        positionOfDrag.y - middle.y
                    ) - atan2(
                        previousPosition.x - middle.x,
                        previousPosition.y - middle.y
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    ) { measurables, constraints ->

        val placeables = measurables.map { it.measure(constraints) }
        val layoutWidth = constraints.maxWidth
        val layoutHeight = constraints.maxHeight

        layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
            val childCount = placeables.size
            if (childCount == 0) return@layout

            val middleX = layoutWidth / 2f
            val middleY = layoutHeight / 2f


            middle = Offset(middleX, middleY)

            val angleBetween = 2 * PI / childCount
            val radius =
                min(
                    layoutWidth - (placeables.maxByOrNull { it.width }?.width ?: 0),
                    layoutHeight - (placeables.maxByOrNull { it.height }?.height ?: 0)
                ) / 2

            size = (radius * 2).toDp()

            placeables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
                val angle = index * angleBetween - PI / 2 - dragAngle
                val x = middleX + (radius) * cos(angle) - placeable.width / 2f
                val y = middleY + (radius) * sin(angle) - placeable.height / 2f
                placeable.placeRelative(x = x.toInt(), y = y.toInt())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the calling side:

```
CircularView {
repeat(10) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                Color(
                    red = random.nextInt(255),
                    green = random.nextInt(255),
                    blue = random.nextInt(255)
                ), shape = CircleShape
            )
            .size(50.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center

    ) {
        Text(text = it.toString(), fontSize = 12.sp, color = Color.White)
    }
}
```

}